# How to stop Windows 8 from automatically signing into MSN?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, windows-8, messaging

In the Metro environment I have the Messaging app, and it automatically signs to MSN, which I do not want. How can I turn off this feature?

Comment: +1 I also have this problem, sadly none of the answers apply as they are about WLM and not about Messaging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign out of messenger on Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/404399/sign-out-of-messenger-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the Charms (move your mouse to the upper right corner or press Win + I) while you are inside of the Messaging app and click on **Settings**, then **Options**. Move the slider to the left to permanently sign off.

However this will sign you out of both MSN and Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose "Settings" (swipe from the right, or press WIN+I), and choose "Permissions" there is are options for "Notifications" and "Lock Screen".

If you turn off those options, the app should not connect to anything unless you explicitly open it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for all the troubles related to your FB or any other personal accounts

Open the People app, it should probably show your FB account if you have already synced one. Then go to **Settings** by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and select **Accounts**, you can see an option there "Manage account online". Click on that and a browser window will open up asking you to login to your Microsoft account. Do that and there is an option "Manage accounts", select FB and at the bottom you can see the "Remove account completely" option. Click that and you are done. When you come back to the People app it will ask you to sign in to your Microsoft account again.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open Start Menu Settings.
2. Open Settings.
3. Select Show Administrative tools.
4. Go to applications and launch Services. Then Find Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant , stop it and disable this service.

Screenshots by the link: http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/windows-messenger/  (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: That will make it stop from logging in to other services too. Then, you won't be able to fully utilize services such as the Windows Store.