# Sign out of messenger on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-live-messenger, xbox360

I just installed the Windows 8 Consumer Preview. Just going through the default procedure, I let it use my Xbox Live account to create a user.

When I then went and turned on my Xbox, it now notified me that I was logged into Messenger in two locations.

I went back to Windows 8, and turned my Live account into a local account on that machine. But when I then turned the Xbox again, I got the same message.

Is there a way to just 'sign out of messenger' on Windows 8? Or is there a location to even see where I am signed in at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Windows 8 from automatically signing into MSN?](http://superuser.com/questions/402902/how-to-stop-windows-8-from-automatically-signing-into-msn)

Answer (score 18):

I actually found a way to accomplish this.
You are still signed in with your Live account in all the other services, but not in Messenger. Other people will also see you as offline, but you can be online on other instances (e.g. your other computer) without interferences (you will be shown and seen online there).

Open the Messages App, go to the upper or lower right-hand corner and wait till the overhead menu appears. Choose "Settings" from here. You will be presented with some settings, choose "Options" (I only have the German version, I suppose it reads Options in English). There is only one settings, it should read something like "Send/receive messages". Turn this setting off and you will be offline in MSN on Windows 8.

Side effect: You will also be signed out of other messaging services in the Messaging app, but because (for now) it only supports Facebook, this shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: when you are in an app and hit windows key + c you go to settings directly. it's just a fast common shortcut keycombination for windows 8 :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Messaging app installed? Try going there, pull up the command bar, and change your status to "Appear offline". Or, just uninstall Messaging (but this will also uninstall People, Mail, Calendar).

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to right bottom corner.
2. Then *Settings*
3. *Account*
4. Click the account, e.g. *Hotmail*
5. Scroll down and you can see *Remove all accounts* .
6. Click it once and then once again – now you are logged out.

Answer (score 2):

the simplest one, i found right now,
when a user is signed in, in any of the windows service, he would be automatically signed in to other services as well,like messaging,calendar, mail etc etc. what i did to sign off from all these services - i went to messaging app. clicked on it. then a window appeared. on the right hand upper corner there is sth like-"connected to ". just below it, there's an arrow, where one can find easily an option to "remove all your accounts".(this would ultimately sign off the user account from all these respective services without disabling/uninstalling anything.).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Start Menu Settings.
2. Open Settings.
3. Select Show Administrative tools.
4. Go to applications and launch Services. Then Find Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant , stop it and disable this service.

Screenshots by the link: http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/windows-messenger/  (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Link-only answer are a no-no on SuperUser due to potential future link-rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answer.

Comment: like this or more?

Comment: That is how to stop the auto-sign-in. How can I sign in and out at will, apppear offline, etc?

Answer (score 0):

To logout from mail account in Window 8 Mail App;

- Firstly you should remain open your mail account
- Move your arrow to side to open the charm and click on Setting
- Choose account and go down to Remove Account

Have a nice day.