# How to log out of Metro Messaging app?

Tags: windows-8-preview, windows-live-messenger, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop Windows 8 from automatically signing into MSN?](https://superuser.com/questions/402902/how-to-stop-windows-8-from-automatically-signing-into-msn)

At some point my Metro Messaging app in Windows 8 got logged into my MSN account. Now it occasionally intercepts my MSN messenger messages from my desktop MSN client. Anyway of logging it out without uninstalling it?